# How to convert Tensorflow Object Detection API model to TFLite?

Tags: python-3.6, object-detection, tensorflow-lite, object-detection-api, tensorflow2.x

I am trying to convert a Tensorflow Object Detection model(**ssd-mobilenet-v2-fpnlite**, from [TensorFlow 2 Detection Model Zoo](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/tf2_detection_zoo.md)) to TFLite. First of all, I train the model using the [model_main_tf2.py](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/model_main_tf2.py) and then I use the [export_tflite_graph_tf2.py](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/export_tflite_graph_tf2.py) to export a saved model(.pb). However, when it comes to convert the .pb file to .tflite it throws this **error**:

```
OSError: SavedModel file does not exist at: /content/gdrive/My Drive/models/research/object_detection/fine_tuned_model/saved_model/saved_model.pb/{saved_model.pbtxt|saved_model.pb}
```

To convert the .pb file I used:

```
import tensorflow as tf

SAVED_MODEL_PATH = os.path.join(os.getcwd(),'object_detection', 'fine_tuned_model', 'saved_model', 'saved_model.pb')
# SAVED_MODEL_PATH: '/content/gdrive/My Drive/models/research/object_detection/exported_model/saved_model/saved_model.pb'

converter = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_saved_model(SAVED_MODEL_PATH)
converter.optimizations = [tf.lite.Optimize.DEFAULT]
converter.experimental_new_converter = True
converter.target_spec.supported_ops = [tf.lite.OpsSet.TFLITE_BUILTINS, tf.lite.OpsSet.SELECT_TF_OPS]
tflite_model = converter.convert()

open("detect.tflite", "wb").write(tflite_model)
```

or "tflite_convert" from command line, but with the same error. I also tried to run it with the latest tf-nightly version as it suggests [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/running_on_mobile_tf2.md), but the outcome is the same. I tried to pass the path with various ways, it seems like the .pd is not well written (not the right file). Is there a way to manage to convert the model to tflite so as to implement it to android? Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your saved_model path should be "/content/gdrive/My Drive/models/research/object_detection/fine_tuned_model/saved_model/". It is the folder instead of files in that folder

For quick test, try to type in terminal

```
tflite_convert \
  --saved_model_dir="path to saved_folder" \
  --output_file="path to tflite file u want to save"
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't have enough reputation to just comment but the problem here seems to be your `SAVED_MODEL_PATH`.

You could try to hardcode the path and remove the `.pb` file. I don't remember exactly what's the trick here but it's definitively due to the path